# Django loading fixtures (not from installed apps) in tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, fixtures, testcase

Is there a way to load fixtures that do NOT reside in appname/fixtures? According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#fixture-loading), fixtures have to be in directory of INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 4):

You can define additional locations to search for fixtures using the `FIXTURE_DIRS` setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FIXTURE_DIRS

Answer (score 1):

Just had to programmatically call 'loaddata' using call_command. You can do it in setUp.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.management import call_command

class GlobalSetup(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Manually calling loaddata to import fixures 
        # that are not in INSTALLED_APPS
        call_command('loaddata', 'cur_dir/fixtures_name', verbosity=0)
```